# Internal watch failed: ENOSPC: System limit for number of file watchers reached, watch

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, npm

[I have an issue with setup server script in npm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWzDu.png)

After removing Deno I receive this problem with setup script for server... How i can fix it?

Comment: Try `echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p`